# How do I execute ant.java properly from gradle?

Tags: java, ant, groovy, jar, gradle

I'm trying to invoke a jar, but I don't see any output when I run the command without args, and when I *do* run with args, I get the following error:

```
[ant:java] The args attribute is deprecated. Please use nested arg elements.
[ant:java] Java Result: 1
```

How do I invoke ant.java in such a way that I see output and can pass arguments?

```
task compressJs(){
  ant.java(jar:"lib/yuicompressor-2.4.6.jar",fork:true,args:['js/file.js', '-o', 'build/js/file.js'])
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your args should be specified like this:

```
ant.java(jar:"lib/yuicompressor-2.4.6.jar",fork:true) {
    arg(value: "js/file.js")
    arg(value: "-o")
    arg(value: "build/js/file.js")
}
```

Pretty much it is the same as you would do with ant except using the Groovy style markup builder instead of XML.

By default your output will go to the screen. If you want to redirect it, set the 'output' property.

Comment: The output is still being squashed.

Comment: How to send in a parametric argument?
ex. `command --key value`

Comment: Why do I get the output: **Java result 1**?  Is that an error.

Comment: You can get the output like this: ant.java(...., outputproperty: 'op') { // stuff } println ant.properties.op

Comment: How do you give it a `classpath`?

Answer (score 8):

As I said before, it's best to use the `JavaExec` task. To execute a Jar, you can do:

```
task exec(type: JavaExec) { 
    main = "-jar" 
    args relativePath("lib/yuicompressor-2.4.6.jar") 
    args ... // add any other args as necessary 
}
```

The comments in http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1274 also explain how to capture output from `ant.java`, but using `JavaExec` is the better solution.

Comment: Can this be forked, though?

Comment: Oops, I meant spawn (as in ant.java's spawn), not fork.

Comment: What's the difference? Do you want to run it async? That's not currently possible with `JavaExec`.

Comment: This doesn't work.  It does not invoke the **-jar** command, and nothing runs.

Answer (score 1):

To get the output set the --info flag on gradle or set the outputproperty on ant.java:

```
task compressJs(){
  ant.java(outputproperty: 'cmdOut', jar:"lib/yuicompressor-2.4.6.jar",fork:true,args:['js/file.js', '-o', 'build/js/file.js'])
  println(ant.project.properties.cmdOut)
}
```

Comment: The args is wrong and should be specified like Chris Dail did below. What output did you expect to get; and do you get that when running on command line?

Comment: Of course I used correct argument structure. The cmdOut property itself had no effect on output. When you run the jar directly, it puts output to System.out. When invoked through gradle and ant.java, this output goes nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

The Ant task needs to be invoked in the *execution* phase, not the *configuration* phase:

```
task compressJs() << { // note the <<
  ant.java(...)
}
```

You could also use Gradle's JavaExec task. See the documentation.

Comment: This doesn't seem to change anything, regardless of whether or not it's semantically correct.

Comment: Not answering your question, but why don't you use Gradle's JavaExec?

Comment: I don't see an easy way to execute a jar with args and get get the output. The documentation is pretty raw for the task.

Comment: Have you looked [here](http://www.gradle.org/current/docs/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html)? There is no special support for executing a Jar yet; you just have to execute the main class.

Comment: That's not how the application is meant to be invoked. I can't rely on any given main class anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In Addition to Chris Dail's answer , you can also use something like this

```
ant.java(jar:"lib/yuicompressor-2.4.6.jar",fork:true) {
    arg(line: "js/file.js -o build/js/file.js")
}
```

This allows one to declare all the arguments in a single line, very similar to the usage in ANT.